# Is there any way to change the color of <ion-radio> button icon in ionic1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using

```
<ion-radio>
          <div>Item 1</div>
</ion-radio>
```

I tried to apply some css to the existing classes, but unfortunately nothing worked. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Color is not applying for unchecked radio button icons.
[image: PLease see the image: I want traditional radio button icon, and here it is not working for un-checked icons]

Comment: For instance <ion-radio color=""dark""></ion-radio> does not work? If styles exists in your $colors map in src/theme/variables.scss

Comment: I tried that also, but it didn't work for me. It's changing only label text color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get it to work using the `color` attribute like so:

```
<ion-radio color="secondary"></ion-radio>
```

If not, you can style the CSS manually like in the codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVvZqp

Comment: I already tried this. this didn't work for me, I'm not able to change the color of radio icon

Comment: And it doesn't work if you use the `color` attribute on the ion-radio element?

Comment: yes this works, but I'm using <ion-radio>, is there any way for this?

Comment: You are awesome. This is what I want exactly. But it seems somewhere it is overriding some css. I'm unable to apply css on unchecked buttons.

Comment: I suggest debugging the ionic app in your browser using `ionic serve --lab` in cmd in your project directory, then inspecting the radio buttons with the dev console and play around with the options, see what overwrites what.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are using ionic v4 than use this style to change radio button checked color

-->  Radio in popup
.custom-popover {
    ion-radio {
        --color-checked: #75D154;
    }
}

and if you are using simple radio group than paste this style to change the color of radio button

--> Radio Button
ion-radio {`enter code here`
  --color-checked: #75D154;
}
```